GetTransaction API Data
GM,
I'm currently building a python script to pull back fees being paid by bots prespamming token launches.  As additional functionality to this bot, I want to know how much Sol they are planning to spend on the token once it goes live.  I can see the data on Solscan (displayed within the instructions inner arguments > Input Arguments - displayed in lamports).  However, when I pull back the full data from a GetTranscation API request, I cannot see this data anywhere.  I'm using Quicknode for my API requests.  Any help as to where I can find and interpret this data would be really appreciated


Here is an example TX - https://solscan.io/tx/48Binh8kV83RbPH2vVTRpmAxAgHmGtFxSYzmBgnkXqnMroLjhvoKQ2ep9vUGCcjq94yRR6WtnFPFbgHbCPixKg8P
